# Create custom user registration system as like the MVC3 default user registration system

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is the MV3 default user registration system is good enough ? If not How should i create my one as like that default one (with Membership system,Roles system,Profiles system) ? How should i use my DB tables for do that ?

I am new in MVC3 so please give a very good example or a good tutorial link.Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Good Enough" depends on what you need.

I'm using the default [Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) and [Profile Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/014bec1k.aspx) for a fairly busy and complex website.  They are a bit awkward, but get the job done.

The [SQL Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx) is a bit more flexible and [can be used with MVC 3](http://helios.ca/2009/04/22/aspnet-mvc-sqlmembershipprovider/).

If you want to implement a custom membership provider have a look at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider

http://www.danharman.net/2011/06/23/asp-net-mvc-3-custom-membership-provider-with-repository-injection/